# C++ array & function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question about how to pass a 2D array to a function.

I know I can do things like this:

```
void print(int a[][20]){
    cout << "print 1" << a[10][10] << endl;
}
int main(){
    int a[20][20];
    print(a);
    cout << "print 2" << *(*(a+10)+10) << endl;
}
```

print 1 and 2 should give me the same result.
a is a 2D pointer if I am correct.
But I cannot do this

```
void print(int** a){
}
int main(){
    int a[20][20];
    print(a);
    cout << "print 2" << *(*(a+10)+10) << endl;
}
```

The error is:
`cannot convert ‘int (*)[20]’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void print_int(int**)’`
Why I cannot do this?

Comment: You do it like this: `void print(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& a)`. HTH.

Comment: This is a very common error when beginning with c/c++ :)

Answer (score 2):

`int **` is a pointer to a pointer to a int, not a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

Because int ** is a "pointer to pointer to int". It is not same as "pointer to twenty ints". So your second code is same as trying to pass address of street where your house stays instead of passing address of somebody who has address from your home.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using *array* notation, not *pointer* notation as arrays aren't pointers:

```
cout << "print 2" << a[11][11] << endl;
```

Comment: @Angew You're right, and normally I know it, I wanted to say something else but got confused by 2-dimensional arrays in C :-)